# Dynamically create a UIButton within a custom view - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, dynamic

I am creating a custom view that will act like a footer bar so I can pass in several views rather than using IB to add etc saving time and to learn more coding.

My class first creates the background, then I add a UIButton to this, but for some reason the text is not showing and also the click is not firing.

Custom class h file:

```
    @interface menuViewone : UIView {

       IBOutlet UIView *menuback;

    }

    -(void)nextPage;

    -(void)menubackground;
    -(void)nextButton;
```

My custom class m file:

```
    -(void)nextPage{
        NSLog(@"Next Page Clicked");
    }


    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
                }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)menubackground{

        NSLog(@"Menu Background Loaded");
                menuback = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50)];
        [menuback setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [self addSubview:menuback];
        [menuback release];

         [self nextButton];
    }

    -(void)nextButton{

        NSLog(@"Create Next Button");

        UIButton *nextBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        nextBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 60, 50);
        [nextBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        nextBtn.titleLabel.text = @"next";
        nextBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [nextBtn setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:nextBtn]; 

    }
```

I am calling it in my main m file using:

```
    #import "menuViewone.h"

    .......

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

       menuViewone *menu = [[menuViewone alloc] init];
       [menu menubackground];
       [self.view addSubview:menu];
       [menu release];

        [super viewDidLoad];


    }
```

So at the moment I get a yellow footer background with a red button to the left, but no action or label

1: whats going on?
2: am I doing this right?

**UPDATE**
I have solved the issue of the text not showing which was when I was releasing the button which would auto release as mentioned below.

So now my only issue is that the click event is not working, and I do not get my NSLog output from the -(void)nextPage{.. method.

Here is the test one I created:

```
   UIButton *nextBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

  [nextBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 80,40)];

  [nextBtn setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [nextBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];

  [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  [self addSubview:nextBtn];
```

but it seems as if the 
       [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

is not firing?

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I have tried the following piece of code on the root/ my view Controller.

viewController.h
        - (void)nextPage: (id)sender;

viewController.m

```
 -(void)nextPage: (id)sender
  {
     NSLog(@"Next Page Clicked");
  }
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

       CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 280, 100, 30 );
      UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
      [button setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.view addSubview: button];
     [button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(nextPage:) 
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

 .....
```

And when I tried this the clicked method worked.

So it must be something to do with my custom class view and the setting of my button as if its not recognised it??

Thanks Si

Comment: this is objectivec, not "xcode" . xcode is the IDE.

Comment: Updated it to objectivec sorry.

Comment: I we have helped you solving your issue, please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

NextPage does not get called because you use the incorrect signature for the selector. in:

```
    [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

the colon after nextPage means "a method called nextPage with a single argument. Something like `nextPage:(int)pageNumber {}` where you have `nextPage {}`. If you change that line to:

```
    [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Your action will be called.

The label I'm less sure of but it is probably not displaying because of the combination of button style and state. You should definitely replace `UIButtonTypeCustom` with `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`. If that doesn't work make sure that the state of the button matches the state you set text for. You can either set the state of the button or, set the text for more states (with the latter being preferable).

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you are creating a button with a class method, in this case you should not release it. The class method returns an autoreleased object.
Second is a memory leak in your next code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        menuViewone *menu = [[menuViewone alloc] init];
       [menu menubackground];
       [self.view addSubview:menu];


        [super viewDidLoad];


    }
```

You **should** release *menu variable as it is a local one and it gets a retain when you add it as a subview.

So first correct your memory leaks, after that we will talk.

**Update:** And to add to mister not arrogant answer, I would choose UIControlEventTouchDown instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside. UIControlEventTouchUpInside event is very strange, some times it does not send notifications to your handlers.

Comment: "So first correct your memory leaks, after that we will talk." -1 for being arrogant.

Comment: I'm sorry? Arrogant? I just want to help this guy :)

Comment: then you should point out that defect and the give him the fix he asked for. No need to make him feel small about the memory leaks.

Comment: I did not make him small. My answer is a good try, as a solution, cause lots of mistakes like this may also come from memory leaks. And solving memory leaks, might solve his problems.

Comment: Thanks for the replies I will have a look and feed back, the menu release is my mistake and its was on there just not on the code example i posted :-) thanks

Comment: I have release that little issue from earlier :-)

I have discovered as mention that the [nextBtn release] was causing my text not to display and also when I close the emulator it gave me the EXE_BAD_ACCESS.

Anyway removing this it displayed the text and no error.

But the main issue is that it will not fire the click event:
        [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

does not display the NSLog message in the nextPage method?

Comment: As I mentioned above, try replacing UIControlEventTouchUpInside with UIControlEventTouchDown

Comment: Try to replace this init (menuViewone *menu = [[menuViewone alloc] init];) with initWithFrame;